# Find the last commit containing 'word1'

Tags: django, git, commit

In a big django project, I remember we change `'word1'` by `'word2'`, but I don't even know what is `'word2'`. However, I know I could find it with `'word1'`. In other words, I would like to find the commit where I changed `'word1'` to `'word2'`. How could I do such thing? How could I find the last commit with `'word1'`?

Comment: Do you know at least one commit that still has `word1`?  For example was `word1` in the initial commit?

Comment: We have 3000 commits so far. The last commit with `'word1'` is probably 1000 commits ago. So I don't even know one commit with `'word1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [`-S` option of `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Sltstringgt)

```
git log -S word1 --patch
```

Will display all the commit with active change containing `'word1'` and changing it.

Comment: Is it possible to display that word with a specific color?

Comment: Not with git, you have to use another program for that like `grep`: `git log -S word1 --patch | grep '\(^commit\|word1\)'` will display the commit hash and the lines with `'word1'`

Answer (score 0):

Not the lightest thing to do but I would also consider using git grep.... looping... something like this:

```
git rev-list | while read revision; do
    lines=$( git grep word1 $revision | wc -l )
    if [ $lines -ne 0 ]; then
        echo Found it on revision $revision
        git grep word1 $revision
        break
    fi
done
```